# SaveAs gets a Subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, save-as

I have a project where I am opening Excel files and saving them in a different folder.  All is well until SaveAs is called.  I am able to save the file, but I am not able to SaveAs.  I am calling Excel from MS Access where all of my code resides.  Here is my code with a few of the variations I attempted.  All 3 produced the same error.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
    Option Compare Database

    Sub Testsave()
    Dim objexcel1 As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB1 As Excel.Workbook

    Set objexcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'objexcel1.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set xlWB1 = objexcel1.Workbooks.Open("C:\Submission File.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)
    xlWB1.Application.Visible = True

'Try 1
    xlWB1.Application.Workbooks("Submission File.xlsx").SaveAs FileName:="C:\Submission File3", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

'Try 2
    xlWB1.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Submission File2", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

'Try 3
    xlWB1.Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "T:\Submission File2.xlsx", AccessMode:=xlExclusive,     ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges


    xlWB1.Close (True)

    End Sub
```

The file to save in another directory.

Comment: Do you have access to those Excel constants in Access.

Comment: **1.** `xlWorkbookNormal` is for `.xls`. For `.xlsx` use `xlOpenXMLWorkbook ` **2.** You have already defined `xlWB1` as workbook. Simply use that. `xlWB1.SaveAs FileName:="T:\Submission File2.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`

Answer (score 1):

Workbooks("Submission File.xlsx") is wrong. The index in the brackets should be a number. Amend the line to the following and your code should work

```
'Try 1
    xlWB1.Application.Workbooks(1).SaveAs FileName:="C:\Submission File3", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

Also, you are testing Excel VBA in Access. Access automatically appends the first line (Option Compare Database). If you copy the entire function into VBA Editor in Excel, exclude the first line; then you can run the function and Excel VBA will show which exact line caused the error.

It would be good to familiarize yourself with the Immediate window in the VBA Editor too. When you run into an error, click pass the error message and type the following code in the Immediate Window would give you some clue.

```
?xlWB1.Application.Workbooks(1).Name
C:\Submission File.xlsx
```